# in trouble with JMeter 2.9 to access page with SAML/SSO protocol

Tags: header, single-sign-on, jmeter, saml, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to test a web application with jmeter 2.9, my application works under SSO configuration which administers WSO2 identity server, I have two samplers the first access my application but  a filter redirects to the login page from identity server, so i have a second sampler HTTP Request, this second sampler tries to access the login page but it does not get access to the next page which is the first page of my application, also I have not errors in jmeter logs. The identity server handles the https protocol and its own certificate

According to the documentation of Jmeter I have no problems with certificates and the Jmeter should present a diaolog box asking if I want to accept the certificate Jmeter but it is not doing this. The configuration to second sampler is the next

```
Server Name or IP:   localhost
PortNumber:   9443
Protocol [http]:   https
Path:   samlsso?SAMLRequest=${valorSAMLRequest}

- send parameters with request -

username:   admin
password:   admin
```

The other values are the defaults.

When the test runs in the jmeter my listener shows the request in two ways

[image: Request from Raw tab]

[image: Request from HTTP tab]

The response is the html text from the IS's login page, it is because the flow does not pass to the application home page

where is it wrong?

Comment: Try to show request/response tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user1750701 this link helped me going further in my investigation. I had to change some of the login-parameters' names, but this also depends on the version of the Identity Srever and the SAML-Feature.
http://malalanayake.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/saml2-sso-load-testing-with-wso2is-4-0-0/

Hope it helps